# Tools and techniques for refactoring CSS

Tags: css

I need to do this more generally, but a fine current example is my two menus.  I have two menu classes, `horizontal-menu` and `vertical-menu`, and two sets of rules for elements like `ul`, `li`, and `a` under these classes.  Many of these rules have things in common, like the `color` value for `a` elements.  I would like to refactor the common rules and values into a 'super-class' called `menu`, and the have only override values in my `horizontal-menu` and `vertical-menu` classes.  Is there a tool (besides the tool asking this question) that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool for this kind of problem is [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), a framework for defining rules which are then compiled into css for use in production. It allows you to define variables in much the same way as an imperative language.

It also has other helpful concepts such as *mixins* which allow the definition of a set of css properties which would be regularly used together, such that you can include that block of properties in multiple standard CSS rules. The power being that you can then edit that mixin in one place, changing the properties and having that change propagate to any CSS rule in which the mixin has been used.

I discovered Compass, and learnt how it should be used thanks, to [a screencast](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/88-intro-to-compass-sass/) by [Chris Coyier](http://chriscoyier.net) at [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com)

The only problem in this case (and most cases in fact) is that you really have to start from scratch with Compass, or find a way of integrating its work-flow into your existing one.

Comment: The CSS pre-processor that the Compass framework uses is called Sass (http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [csscss](http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/) a shot. I wrote it in order to have an idea of how much I'm repeating myself in my own stylesheets. I'm obviously biased, but a number of people have found it helpful too. SASS, LESS, and Compass support are baked in.

Another great tool is [helium](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) which is a javascript tool that runs in the browser and lets you know of any unused rules.